# Помогите исправить ошибку "'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python

Передо мной стоит следующая задача : Вам нужно запросить у пользователя возраст. Добавить условие
при котором возраст будет выводиться с правильным словом: "год", "года"
или "лет". Т.е. "29 лет" или "4 года". При запуске выдаёт ошибку `"'int' object is not callable"`, помогите исправить :

```
age = input("Сколько вам? ");
result = int(age) % 10;

if result(2 or 3 or 4) :
    print('Вам ' + age + ' года');
if age(1 or 21 or 31 or 41 or 51 or 61 or 71 or 81 or 91):
    print('Вам ' + age + ' год');
if result(5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 0):
    print('Вам ' + age + ' лет');
if age(11 or 12 or 13 or 14):
    print('Вам ' + age + ' лет');
else :
    print("Вам больше ста лет");
```

Comment: Сначала у вас `result = int(age) % 10`, т.е. `result` - это переменная типа `int`. А потом вы его как функцию вызываете `if result(2 or 3 or 4)` -

Comment: Отлично. В `result` Вы кладете целочисленное значение. Допустим там лежит число 2. Затем, Вы пытаетесь вызвать это число как функцию 2(). Как Вы себе это представляете?)

Answer (score 2):

```
if result(2 or 3 or 4) :
```

Что-то вы странное проверяете. Нужно так, например:

```
if result in (2, 3, 4):
```

И далее везде по коду тот же принцип.

Кроме того, `age` у вас строка, нужно его тоже в `int` преобразовать, либо проверять на совпадение со строками, а не с числами.